# Google streetview metadata request for multiple positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-street-view

I have a page with a list of places with GPS coordinates. I want to put a StreetView button for the places where I have StreetView available but not for the other places. 
The places are loaded dynamically and I have to make a metadata request to the [StreetView Metadata API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata) for each place. 
If street view exists I will activate the button, else I will disable it or delete it.

Is it possible to make a single request to the API for a list of locations instead of multiple requests, one for each location?

My code snippet is something like this, at the moment:

```
for (var l in locations) {
    if (coordsList[l]) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview/metadata?location='+coordslist[l]+'&key='+googleKey
        }).done(function (res) {
            //if streetView exists activate button
            if (res.status == 'OK') {
                $('[name="streetview"]').eq(l).prop('disabled', false);
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Which will make a hundred async requests to the API if I have a hundred places.